# Generate a combination of a pair from a array (abc -> ab:bc:ca or ac:ba:cb)

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I got an array like

```
print_r($emails);
```

Displays:

```
Array ( [0] => email1 [1] => email2 [2] => email3 [3] => email4 [4] => email5 )
```

I would like to create combinations of a pair from `$emails`, with an output example:

- email1 has as combi email4
- email2 has as combi email1
- email3 has as combi email5
- email4 has as combi email2
- email5 has as combi email3

So, you can't have "email1 has as combi email1", nor "email1 has as combi email3, and email2 has as combi email3".

Also note that this output can be different anytime, and the `$emails` array has a variable number of items (The example had 5, but it can be 3 or more).

I'm trying to create a code for this for hours now... Search all over the web. I really hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Are you creating some sort of list? What do you mean by: `email1 has as combi email4`. Can you explain that more clearly?

Comment: Well, eventually I want to send an email to email1, saying: "Your partner is email4".
So, the combinations can either be stored in a new array, or send directly.

Thanks for having interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, each email must have a "combi" (whatever that is) to exactly one distinct email.

That amounts to building a graph where each node has exactly one outgoing (and not self-refering) vertex, which implies it also has a single incoming vertex.

This means producing one or all graphs that are partitioned into cycles with no singletons.

For instance, for 5 elements, you can have either one big 1->2->3->4->5 cycle or two 1->2->3 / 4->5 cycles

Creating all possible combinations does not look like a trivial task to me, and though I'm no graphs expert I don't think the problem is common enough to have been studied by the hard math dudes.

The best approximation I can offer is as follows:

1. partition your "emails" into subsets that contain at least 2 elements
2. create cycles inside each partition

The problem with this approach is to decide how to partition your initial set to get an homogeneous result. For instance, in the 5 elements case, how often do you want to have a single 5 elements cycle instead of a 3/2 partition?

I settled for a simple approach: the initial set is first cut at any position that would not produce a singleton, then one of the remaining part undergoes the same process until the initial set is exhausted.
A recursive split of both (non-empty) subsets would probably produce a more homogeneous result, but since I'm not quite sure this answer matches your expectations, I'll leave it at that for the moment.

```
<?php
$num_nodes = 6; // number of "e-mails"

$nodes = range (1, $num_nodes); // these represent your e-mails
$vertex = Array();              // these represent your "has as combi " relation

shuffle($nodes); // random pick order

// partition nodes into subsets of at least 2 elements
$cycles = array();
while (count($nodes) > 0)
{
    $len = rand (1, count($nodes)-2);
    if ($len == 1) $len = 0; // take all remaining nodes
    $cycles[] = array_slice ($nodes, $len);
    array_splice ($nodes, $len);
}

// create cycles within each subset
echo "Partitions:\n";
foreach ($cycles as $cycle)
{
    foreach ($cycle as $node) echo "$node->"; echo "\n";
    $len = count ($cycle);
    for ($i = 0 ; $i != $len ; $i++) $vertex[$cycle[$i]] = $cycle[($i+1)% $len];
}

// here you go...
echo "\nRelations:\n";
foreach ($vertex as $origin=>$destination) echo "$origin -> $destination\n";

?>
```

Example output:

```
C:\Dev\PHP\_StackOverflow\PHP>php email_graph.php
Partitions:
3->5->1->
4->6->2->

Relations:
3 -> 5
5 -> 1
1 -> 3
4 -> 6
6 -> 2
2 -> 4

C:\Dev\PHP\_StackOverflow\PHP>php email_graph.php
Partitions:
1->4->
6->5->3->2->

Relations:
1 -> 4
4 -> 1
6 -> 5
5 -> 3
3 -> 2
2 -> 6

C:\Dev\PHP\_StackOverflow\PHP>php email_graph.php
Partitions:
3->4->6->5->1->2->

Relations:
3 -> 4
4 -> 6
6 -> 5
5 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
```

Comment: You're amazing! With some minor edits it does exactly what I want!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading through your question and your clarification in your comment, I would say what you need is a circular linked list. Such as:

```
  email1 -> email2 -> email3 -> email1
```

As long as there are 3 or more emails, no one will have to talk to themselves or some email taken by someone else. The position of email1 and email3 and all that does not matter so it can be random as you mention.

In simple terms when there are 3 people:

- Person1 looks at person2
- Person2 looks at person3
- Person3 looks at person1

It never matters who is person1, person2 or person3. If Bill Gates was one of the 3 people, it wouldn't matter which one of them he is. The fact is that he will never look at himself or some who is already been looked at by someone else. That is keeping it simple for me.

I hope I have not over-simplified it.